# The following statement $\left(p\rightarrow q\right)\left[(~\sim p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow q\right]$ is

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

The following statement $\left(p\rightarrow q\right)\left[(~\sim p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow q\right]$ is

$$(p\rightarrow q)\left[\sim(\sim p \rightarrow  q) \vee q\right] $$
$$(p\rightarrow q)\left[\sim(p \vee q) \vee q\right] $$
$$(p\rightarrow q)\left[\left(\sim p \land \sim q\right) \vee q\right]$$
$$(p\rightarrow q)\left[\left(\sim p \vee q\right) \land \left(\sim q \vee q\right)\right]$$
$$(p\rightarrow q)\left[\left(\sim p \vee q\right) \land \left(\sim q \vee q\right)\right]$$

$$(p\rightarrow q)\left[\left(\sim p \vee q\right) \land t\right] \text {where t denotes tautology}$$
$$(p\rightarrow q)\left[\left(\sim p \vee q\right)\right] $$
$$(p\rightarrow q)\left[p\rightarrow q\right] $$

Now from here how to solve further, is there any notion of multiplication as there is no logical connective between $\left(p\rightarrow q\right)$ and $\left[p\rightarrow q\right]$

Actual answer is tautology

Comment: What does it mean the juxtaposition of the two formulas ? An "and" ? If so, why  not use $\land$ ?

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what you are saying, can you please explain.

Comment: How we have to read $(p→q)[p→q]$ as $(p→q) \land [p→q]$ ?

Comment: but the actual answer is tautology

Comment: but the formula is wrongly written...

Comment: where? can you point out the mistake by step no?

Comment: Every step; start from beginning: what does it mean $(p→q)[( ∼p→q)→q]$ ? A connective is  missing … There is no "multiplication" in propositional logic.

Comment: so are you saying the question is wrong or I have done something wrong.

Comment: YES ......… :-)

Comment: The problem is with the notation, which I don't understand either, and appears to be nonstandard.  The successive sentences inside the square brackets constitute a derivation (correct, as far as I can tell) of the equivalence of the first one, $\ (\sim p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow q\ $, to the last one, $\ p\rightarrow q\ $.  The problem is with the juxtaposition of each of those bracketed sentences with a preceding one, $\ p\rightarrow q\ $, inside parentheses. Can you  (preferably) explain what that juxtaposition means, or point to a source that explains it?

Answer (score 1):

As Mauro points out in the Comments, there is an operator missing. Probably the statement is supposed to be:

$$\left(p\rightarrow q\right)\color{red}\to \left[(~\sim p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow q\right]$$

With that, you can proceed exactly the same way you did, and thus end up with:

$$\left(p\rightarrow q\right)\to (p \to q)$$

$$\neg(p\rightarrow q)\lor (p \to q)$$

$$t$$